# The same code, different results in v2 and v3

Tags: pine-script

I try to migrate the script from v2 to v3 PineScript. However, it turns out that in v3 the same code returns different values. How it's possible and what I did wrong? Below you may find the code of this script.

That's how it looks like on the chart
https://www.tradingview.com/x/itg3HS0T/?

Test1 - v2, green, gray lines
Test2 - v3, pink, blue lines

Thank you in advance for your help!:)

```
//@version=2

study("Test2",overlay=true)

long_timeframe = input(title="Long timeframe", type=resolution, defval="180")
short_timeframe = input(title="Long timeframe", type=resolution, defval="60")

step_shift = input(0,"Step Shift")


ha_symbol = heikinashi(tickerid)
long_ha_close = security(ha_symbol, long_timeframe, hlc3)
short_ha_close = security(ha_symbol, short_timeframe, hlc3)


long_step = ema(long_ha_close[step_shift],1)
short_step = ema(short_ha_close[step_shift],1)

plot(long_step,title="LongStep",color=white,linewidth=2,style=line)
plot(short_step,title="ShortStep",color=silver,linewidth=2,style=line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is due to the fact that `security()` function's `lookahead` parameter has a default value of `on` in v2 and `off` in v3, so need to set it to `on` explicitly in v3.

```
//@version=3

study("Test3",overlay=true)

long_timeframe = input(title="Long timeframe", type=resolution, defval="180")
short_timeframe = input(title="Long timeframe", type=resolution, defval="60")

step_shift = input(0,"Step Shift")


ha_symbol = heikinashi(tickerid)
// These 2 lines yield same result as v2 version of the script.
long_ha_close = security(ha_symbol, long_timeframe, hlc3, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
short_ha_close = security(ha_symbol, short_timeframe, hlc3, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
// To avoid repainting, these 2 lines are preferable.
// long_ha_close = security(ha_symbol, long_timeframe, hlc3[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
// short_ha_close = security(ha_symbol, short_timeframe, hlc3[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)


long_step = ema(long_ha_close[step_shift],1)
short_step = ema(short_ha_close[step_shift],1)

plot(long_step,title="LongStep",color=aqua,linewidth=2,style=line)
plot(short_step,title="ShortStep",color=fuchsia,linewidth=2,style=line)
```